# Could not find com.commercetools.sdk:commercetools-sdk-java-api:17.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: commercetools

i am facing issue while trying to setup commercetools sdk v2 , while hitting command gradlew bootRun if anyone can help please help

D:\toolsv2\commercetools-sdk-v2\examples\spring>gradlew bootRun

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.commercetools.sdk:commercetools-sdk-java-api:17.1.0-SNAPSHOT.
> Required by:
> project :
> Could not find com.commercetools.sdk:commercetools-okhttp-client3:17.1.0-SNAPSHOT.
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I tried to changes version from gradlew.wrapper.properties file

buts its couldnt help

Comment: Usually you (or maven/gradle) will find only released versions on central. Ty using 17.1.0 (without SNAPSHOT) as version.

Answer (score 0):

Run once in the main folder of the repository

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

This will build the SDK artifacts with the required version number and install it locally in your maven repository. Afterwards the example should be able to find run.

Comment: I updated the repository. The examples are now depending on a published version from maven central.